# Python Type()function returning only Changed Variable Type

Tags: python

```
x=1
type(x)
x="sss"
type(x)
```

The Output is only `str`..

Why aren't there two outputs; `int` and `str`?
Im using Jupyter notebook

Comment: where did you run this?

Comment: What do you mean by `outputs`? it really isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: Probably in some place that only shows the output of the last expression...

Comment: iM running this on Jupyter Notebook

Comment: @ThiefMaster maybe

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put print statements before them. Otherwise only the most recent one will print to screen

```
x=1
print(type(x))
x="sss"
print(type(x))
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using python 3 then, I've edited the answer to work for you

Comment: thanks now thats working out, but can you clear my doubt why does it prints only the str if i dont use print

Comment: As far as I know, it happens only with jupyter notebook, if you save the code without print statements and execute the file from command line, nothing will print without an explicit `print` statements

Comment: calling just a variable, or a function like `type(x)` prints only the most recent command unless it is assigned to something

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running this from a file. If you were in the interpreter (type 'python' in your console) and ran this code line by line, you would see exactly what you are expecting:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>
>>> x = "sss"
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
```

If you want this to work from a file, you need to use print statements e.g.

```
x = 1
print type(x)
x = 'sss'
print type(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the type returns first int and then str, because the variable first was assigned to int and as far as it was reassigned to another data type, the connection between the variable and the int was destroyed and the int deleted from the memory, then the variable was assigned to the str, so the second type call was str.